# Add a new column to an existing mysql table using RMySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, r, merge, rmysql

I need a better idea to work around `RMySQL`.

I have a data frame `myTable` stored in MySQL server. Each row represents an order from a customer, and contains customer name, order ID, date, etc.

My work environment is `R`. Every time I work around this table, I call the data using `RMySQL` package. But I never call the whole data because it is too big to work around. Instead, I filter the data I want, using the statement like this:

```
db <- with(connectionDb, dbConnect(MySQL(),
                                   user = user,
                                   password= password,
                                   dbname = dbname,
                                   host = host))

# connectionDb returns user, password, dbname, host from our credential file.

dbSendQuery(conn = db, 'set character set "utf8"')


cond <- paste('SELECT * FROM myTable
              WHERE organisation LIKE "Ikea" 
              AND dateA >= "2018-05-01" AND dateA < "2018-06-01"')

export <- dbGetQuery(conn = db, statement = cond)
```

And the data frame `export` looks like this in `R`.

```
organisation   Order_ID         dateA       dateB       dateC       dateD  
Ikea                  a    2018-04-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  a    2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29          NA   
Ikea                  a    2018-04-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26 
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b            NA  2018-05-05  2018-08-02  2018-06-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-03          NA          NA   
Ikea                  c    2018-08-02  2018-05-09  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
```

But now, in the table stored in the MySQL server, I want to add a new column `Billed`, which is 1 if we already billed for the order, and 0 if we haven't. So the result should look like this.

```
organisation   Order_ID         dateA       dateB       dateC       dateD    Billed
Ikea                  a    2018-04-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01         0
Ikea                  a    2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29          NA         1
Ikea                  a    2018-04-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26         1
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26         0
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26         1
Ikea                  b            NA  2018-05-05  2018-08-02  2018-06-01         0
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01         1
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-03          NA          NA         1
Ikea                  c    2018-08-02  2018-05-09  2018-07-08  2018-05-26         0
```

I have several ideas to do this, but I'm not sure if they are good.

Idea 1: Call a table with the query above, add to the table a new column in R, and overwrite the whole table using `dbWriteTable` function. But I'm afraid overwriting the whole table could change the format of the original data(str, lgl, numeric etc).

Idea2: Call a table with the query above, make a new data frame `billing` which has only `Order_ID` and `Billed` columns, and in MySQL server merge `billing`  and the original data table by `Tour_ID`.

In either case I'm not sure what's going to happen to the original data table in the server, especially to the rows which were not fetched by the `dbGetQuery` function. Is it going to create a new column `Billed` with 0 and 1 for the overwritten rows, and for the other rows are they going to be all NAs?

So I am looking for any better and stable ideas to complete this task. Is the workflow good? What kind of functions should I use?

Thanks for your any help!

Comment: Where is the logic to determine *Billing*? Likely, it can be done in SQL without R calculations. Please update to show.

Comment: Maybe just write a billing table that contains the Order_Id and the billing flag? Then do the join in MySQL (or send the join through ‘dbGetQuery()’)?